# How to Change Ubuntu to Custom Resolution in VMWare Workstation

Tags: 16.04, display, vmware

Need to change to a resolution that is not already available in `xrandr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following commands, by combining a few previous answers:

- Get required parameters with `cvt 3840 2160 60` (4k@60hz resolution)
- Set the new mode `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync`
- See what is the name of my monitor `xrandr --listmonitors`
- Add the mode with my monitor and the recently configured new mode `xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "3840x2160_60.00"`
- Enable the display resolution `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "3840x2160_60.00"`